# Uso de routelink en el html base

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, typescript

Estoy intentando usar la propiedad *routerLink* de la etiqueta *"a"* en el *html* que carga al iniciar la página.

Esto me funciona bien dentro del *template* de un componente, pero en este caso no es necesario renderizar un componente, ya que el menú es estático.

No uso `href` porque si bien funciona, me recarga toda la página.

```
<a href="/personal"> <!-- functiona pero recarga la pagina-->
<a routerLink="/personal"> <!-- no funciona -->
```

Rutas de *angular*:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/personal", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "personal", component:PersonalComponent },
```

Comment: porque no utilizad ajax solo recargas tus div y evitas cargar toda tu pagina

Comment: porque estoy utilizando angular 2 y lo que necesito es que angular administre las rutas

Comment: Intenta solo poner el `href` de la siguiente manera: <a href="#/personal">

Comment: @arturoblack ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Deberías mirar la página oficial de Angular2, [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html). Básicamente debes comprobar que tienes lo siguiente:

Añadir la ruta base en `src/index.html`:

```
<base href="/">
```

Importar el *router* en `src/app/app.module.ts`:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
```

Definir las rutas en `src/app/app.module.t`:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/personal", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "personal", component:PersonalComponent },
...
```

Por último, debes utilizar la etiqueta `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` en el *template* del componente donde quieras que se incruste el componente que consume el router.

Ahora, ya podrás utilizar los *links* definidos en el router del siguiente modo:

```
 <a routerLink="/personal">Personal</a>
```

Te recomiendo que mires la documentación oficial que te he dejado arriba, pues es de mucha utilidad para poder comprender el funcionamiento de las rutas de Angular 2. Además, tienes ejemplos muy útiles.

Answer (score 0):

Según veo necesitarías poner el tag de routerLink tal que así:

```
<a [routerLink]=['personal']>
```

Sin saber la estructura de tu programa, sólo decirte que tengas en cuenta la localización de tus componentes, ya que el router de Angular2 permite poner:

```
../ para el nivel anterior, quedando así: 
            <a [routerLink]=['../personal']>
./ o nada para el nivel actual, quedando así: 
             <a [routerLink]=['./personal']>
             <a [routerLink]=['personal']>
```

Answer (score 0):

En el router de angular 2 se podría manejar así

```
<a [routerLink]="['/personal']">
```

Comment: Hola @Ramiro. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte. ¿Podrías explicar un poco de qué se trata? Más aún considerando que sólo tiene una diferencia mínima con una de las respuestas publicadas hace mucho, ¿por qué así? ¿Cómo es que esta forma respondería mejor a la pregunta?